# wordpress slideshow content not showing in chrome

Tags: jquery, wordpress

In Chrome this is the code being shown where I cannot see an image in the main window.

```
<div class="szg-main" data-showcaption="disabled" data-caption="ESG-hudson-mirrors-sm-lg-01">     <img class="szg-zoom-photo">     <img class="szg-main-photo"><div class="szg-caption" style="display: none;"></div><div class="szg-medium-loader">       <span></span>       <span></span>       <span></span>       <span></span>       <span></span>       <span></span>       <span></span>       <span></span>​</div></div>
```

However, my image shows in safari without any problem. Can someone help me get to the bottom of this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any plugin for slideshow?

Comment: yes, i am. superzoomgallery